# How to search result from azure search service from filed to filed

Tags: azure-search-.net-sdk

I have two fields in azure index one is Address and other field is Mobileno filed
i want to see result from index address filed contains mobile no

i want to is match mobile no from address:
"search": "search.ismatch('MobileNo','Address')",

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Azure Cognitive Search does not support directly using the value of one field as an input to another field's search expression.
However, you can achieve a similar effect by using filters or adding specific patterns to your search query.

I have created a sample index with below schema:

```py
fields=[  
        {"name": "id", "type": SearchFieldDataType.String, "key": True, "searchable": False},  
        {"name": "Address", "type": SearchFieldDataType.String, "searchable": True},  
        {"name": "MobileNo", "type": SearchFieldDataType.String, "searchable": True},  
       ]
```

And below sample data

```py
sample_data = [  
    {"id": "1", "Address": "123 Main St, New York, NY 10001, +11234567890", "MobileNo": "+11234567890"},  
    {"id": "2", "Address": "456 Elm St, San Francisco, CA 94107, +12223334444", "MobileNo": "+12223334444"},  
    {"id": "3", "Address": "789 Oak Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90001, +13334445555", "MobileNo": "+13334445555"}, 
    {"id": "4", "Address": "123 Main St, New York, NY 10001, +11234567890", "MobileNo": "+12223334444"}, 
]
```

You can use below query to search with same or different value of `MobileNo` in `Address` and `MobileNo` fields.

```py
valueInAddress = '+12223334444'  
valueInMobile = '+12223334444'  
  
# Create the filter expression string  
filter_expression = f"search.ismatch('{valueInAddress}', 'Address')"  
  
results = search_client.search(  
    search_text=valueInMobile,  
    filter=filter_expression,  
    query_type="full",  
    search_mode="all",  
    search_fields=["MobileNo"]  
)  
  
for result in results:  
    print(result)
```

Below is an example output with different value of Mobile Number in Address and MobileNo field:

[image]

you can modify the above sample query based on your requirement and for more details you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-odata-filter-orderby-syntax).